# Eclipse - export runnable jar fails to load plugin (UPDATE)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, executable-jar

The application for which I want to create the plugin is rapidminer. The plugin I created is rather simple : some basic gui staffs.

In order to create it, I followed the instructions by the creators of the application : http://docs.rapid-i.com/files/howtoextend/How%20to%20Extend%20RapidMiner%205.pdf.
I will try to explain as simple as possible how I created the plugin.

There two distinct projects :the one that has to do with the plugin and the other with the main application. After having finished writing the code for the plugin ,I build it with the ant and consequently a new jar file is created in a new folder of the lib directory of the main application. Then I build the main application through ant again creating the main jar file called rapidminer.jar. By loading this jar I can run directly the application.

The plugin works perfectly when I try to load the application normally through eclipse.
However, when I try to create a single jar file ,either using the export as runnable jar option or using fatjar the plugin disappears,that is the application runs but there is no plugin (the same will happen if I delete the plugin jar file that was created and try to load the application).

Both of the .xml files that ant uses were already made and I didn't change anything.

Comment: Could you please expand on what you're trying to do?  If you mean you'd like to combine all of the jars in the plugins/ folder into one, you can't do that.

Comment: By using the "export as runnable jar" option of eclipse I can create a single jar file of my application that works fine.My problem is that I have created also a plugin for my application and the aforementioned jar file can not load this specific plugin(The plugin is located in lib/plugins directory). Obviously, If I try to run my application normally the plugin is loaded. So,my question is if it is possible to make a unique jar file that could also load this plugin.

Comment: Can you update your question (not the comments) with more specifics?  What plugin did you create in eclipse?  What is your application, just a regular java app that you've fatjar'ed?  Which <filename> is trying to load what <filename>?  etc